# The units digit of a power tower of consecutive numbers, from 2019 to 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, power-towers

> Is it possible to find the units digit of
>   $2019^{2018^{2017^{.^{.^{.^{3^{2^{1}}}}}}}}$?

Where the expression contains all natural numbers $[1,2018]$ as powers and $2019$ as the main base.

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Yes, it is easier than it looks - you should try with small powers eg $2,3,4$ and see if you can understand what is going on. Much of the problem here is a distraction - see if you can spot the bits on which the answer will depend.

Comment: When dealing with problems like these, the numbers are sometimes artificially large just to make it seem impressive.  The actual number in question though is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit digit of a number $N$ can be computed as the class of $N$ modulo $10$ and taking its representant in $\{0,1,...,9\}$

You're asking for the units digit of a number of the form $2019^M$. Since the class modulo $10$ of $2019$ is $-\overline1$, you are in fact computing $(-1)^M\bmod 10$.

The result is $1$ if $M$ is even and $9$ if $M$ is odd.

Since your actual $M$ is of the form $M=2018^m$ and $2018$ is even, the former case holds.

Answer (score 6):

HINT

$2019\equiv -1\pmod{10}\Rightarrow 2019^a\equiv (-1)^a\pmod{10}$

Answer (score 2):

$2019^{2018^{2017^{.^{.^{.^{3^{2^{1}}}}}}}}\equiv9^{2018^{2017^{.^{.^{.^{3^{2^{1}}}}}}}}\pmod{10}$

As $\phi(10)=4,(9,10)=1$ and the exponent is multiple of $4$

$9^{2018^{2017^{.^{.^{.^{3^{2^{1}}}}}}}}\equiv9^0\pmod{10}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Have a look at the unit digits of $9,9^2,9^3,9^4,9^5,\dots$.

Would things be different if we switch $9$ with $2019$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT : Assume $a_n=n^{n-1^{n-2^{.^{.^{.^{3^{2^{1}}}}}}}} \mod 10$, then the sequence will be :
$$
1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0,1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0,1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0,1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0,1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0,1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0,1,2,9,4,5,6,9,8,1,0...
$$

Answer (score 0):

If we wanted to be tedious we could note that $$2019\equiv -1\bmod 10\\2018\equiv 2\bmod 4\\2017\equiv 1\bmod 2\\2016\equiv 0\bmod 1$$

and then cut the power tower down to size, by first noting the exponents above the 0 don't have an effect, and that exponent 0 leads to 1 which is useless as an exponent, so we have $-1^2\equiv 1$  as our last digit.  **EDIT** if you wanted to have to figure out the whole tower, you'd need to ask for the last 674 digits.